# C# insert function into BST

Tags: c#, insert, binary-search-tree

before I start I am new to Stack Overflow so I apologize for any incorrectly formatted details within this post, please correct me where needed.

Anyways as for my question, I am also new to C#, I am fairly decent with C++ but I am required to learn C# now. I am working on my insert function for a BST and I can't seem to figure out my mistake. When I run the code the root just keeps getting replaced. I insert the value 5 and then I insert the value 6 and after that my tree only consists of the value 6. I believe it is something with how I am using my properties for Root.Num/.Left/.Right.

Here is my code snippet:

```
private void insertHelper(int value, BSTNode root)
{

    if (this.Root == null) //empty tree, make new node
    {
        BSTNode node = new BSTNode(value);
        this.Root = node;
    }
    else if (value < this.Root.Num)
    {
        insertHelper(value, Root.Left);
    }
    else if (value > this.Root.Num)
    {
        insertHelper(value, Root.Right);
    }
}
```

I feel lost without using pointers even though it should technically be easier not having to deal with them. Could someone please help me point out where this is not logically correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because no matter what parameter you pass you are always using `this`. The immediate fix is using the parameter passed as `root`. Also you need to make sure you do proper null check -

Assuming the first call is something like this - `insertHelper(//value, //the root node)` the following approach might work

```
private void insertHelper(int value, BSTNode root)
{    
    if (root == null) //empty tree, make new node
    {
        BSTNode node = new BSTNode(value);
        this.Root = node;
    }
    else if (value < root.Num)
    {
        if(root.Left != null){
            insertHelper(value, root.Left);
        }else{
            root.Left = new BSTNode(value);
        }
    }
    else if (value > root.Num)
    {
        if(root.Right!= null){
            insertHelper(value, root.Right);
        }else{
            root.Right= new BSTNode(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't adding those extra null checks kind of be the same thing because with the recursion it goes back to that initial check but this time the root it would be checking would be the left node from passing (value, root.Left)?

Comment: Those null check are necessary because of the way you are using `this.Root`, no matter what you sent, `this.Root`` is always the same object. If you want to remove the null checks then, you have to implement it differently.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense, a different implentation being make a temp node to traverse using temp = temp.Left, or temp.Right etc

Comment: this assumes the data entered (nodes) are well ordered as to construct balanced complete BST.....But what if data was not in desired order?in that case we need reshuffle to maintain balanced BST